Where do the boundaries of a befriended class lie exactly?
Since type a has granted friendship to type k, the nested
private type a::t should then also be accessible to k, which
is anywhere within k's scope. This allows for the type-requirement
typename T::t within the requires-clause of static member-
function k::f to be satisfied without failing a member-access check.
I would expect the same behavior when replacing the type-requirement
typename T::t for concept c, as c's definition is the same. However,
MSVC accepts the former but rejects the latter.
But that's not all of it. When utilizing templated alias u outside
of the scope of k—opposed to utilizing templated alias h which
is within k's scope—GCC now also rejects the code.
Are both GCC and MSVC wrong in rejecting this program? This begs
the question; what are the boundaries of friendship granted to another
class?
template<typename T>
concept c = requires { typename T::t; };

template<typename T>
using u = typename T::t;

struct k {
    template<typename T>
    using h = typename T::t;

    template<typename T>
    requires requires {
        typename T::t; // all ok
        typename h<T>; // all ok
        requires c<T>; // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
        typename u<T>; // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope
    } static constexpr bool f() { return true; }
};
class a {
    friend struct k;
    struct t;
};
static_assert(k::f<a>()); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope

Demo

GCC's error message:
<source>:23:22: error: no matching function for call to 'k::f<a>()'
   23 | static_assert(k::f<a>());
      |               ~~~~~~~^~
<source>:17:29: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires
requires{typename T::t;typename T::t;requires c<T>;typename T::t;}
static constexpr bool k::f()'
   17 |     } static constexpr bool f() { return true; }
      |                             ^
<source>:17:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:17:29: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires
requires{typename T::t;typename T::t;requires c<T>;typename T::t;}
static constexpr bool k::f() [with T = a]':
<source>:23:22:   required from here
   23 | static_assert(k::f<a>());
      |               ~~~~~~~^~
<source>:17:29:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T>  requires
requires{typename T::t;typename T::t;requires c<T>;typename T::t;}
static constexpr bool k::f()'
<source>:12:14:   in requirements  [with T = a]
<source>:16:18: note: the required type 'u<T>' is invalid, because
   16 |         typename u<T>;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T> using u = typename T::t
[with T = a]':
<source>:5:7:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class T>
using u = typename T::t [with T = a]'
    5 | using u = typename T::t;
      |       ^
<source>:5:7:   required by substitution of 'template<class T>
using u = typename T::t [with T = a]'
<source>:16:18:   required by substitution of 'template<class T>  requires
requires{typename T::t;typename T::t;requires c<T>;typename T::t;}
static constexpr bool k::f() [with T = a]'
   16 |         typename u<T>;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>:23:22:   required from here
   23 | static_assert(k::f<a>());
      |               ~~~~~~~^~
<source>:5:7: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900
(use '-ftemplate-depth=' to increase the maximum)
    5 | using u = typename T::t;
      |       ^

MSVC's error message:
<source>(23): error C2672: 'k::f': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(17): note: could be 'bool k::f(void)'
<source>(23): note: the associated constraints are not satisfied
<source>(15): note: the concept 'c<a>' evaluated to false
<source>(2): note: 'a::t': cannot access private struct declared in class 'a'
<source>(21): note: see declaration of 'a::t'
<source>(19): note: see declaration of 'a'


@DrewDormann That question is not about befriending classes but about befriending functions.

@Red.Wave Instead of writing such a baseless comment you could also write an answer and explain why you think that is. Clearly, Clang does think that this is how concepts work.

I am not a language lawyer, but there's no consensus about the mater. See: https://x.com/ericniebler/status/1652528944330199042?s=19

@Red.Wave If this is some corner case that is not adequately described by the language, we could make an argument that it really should. Perhaps this has already been addressed to CWG as a DR or something?

In any case, it is clear that both GCC's and MSVC's behavior regarding this case is at the very least inconsistent. As GCC accepts constraint c<T> when defined as requires { typename T::t; } but rejects definition requires { typename u<T>; }. And MSVC accepts requires(typename T::t) { true; } but rejects requires { typename T::t; }.

I don't know. If Eric Neibler didn't go after it, I certainly don't afford to. IMO  concept must have an option indicator to opt in/out of either case. I find both behaviors useful. It would be good if public and friend or private could be used inside requires clauses. I wish I could make a proposition...

This is a completely different question however the answer there may help answer this.  Effectively, IFNDR if the evaluation of a concept ever changes.

@DrewDormann How does that question have any relevance at all? Clearly, in this case there is only one point in the program where concept c is being satisfied.
